# dap-mode exists instead of breaking on crash

Tags: dap

When running applications in dap-mode using `M-x dap-debug`, I can get my applications running via `GDBServer Connect Configuration` & `GDB Run Configuration`.

However when the application crashes I only see the message:

```
Debug session process exited with status: aborted (core dumped)
```

Without the debugger stopping and showing the stack-trace.

`(setq dap-auto-configure-features '(sessions locals controls tooltip))` is set and all the sub-modes are loaded and enabled.

When I run the same program directly via `gdb` a crash or assert will stop and show a stack-trace.

How can `dap-mode` be made to stop instead of exiting?

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by setting `(setq dap-gdb-lldb-debug-program '("/path/to/my/binary"))` instead of the debugger.

`dap-gdb-lldb-debug-program` and `dap-gdb-debug-program` both point to the debuggers.

The `(dap-register-debug-template "Name" (list :program "/path/to/my/binary"))` is used to reference the programs name.